# POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS AND DELETING THE UNWANTED

Tags: forecast-combination

In our company we're capturing scenes from the cars cameras. The customer will say how many scenes they want to be let's say sunny, how many rainy etc.. Let's say we have 100 scenes to be captured. 80% sunny 20% cloudy. From them 70% dry 30% rain, from that 60% dry surface and 40% wet surface. You need to get all the possible combinations of the scenes and find the number of all the combinations needed to get all the requirements. I'm fine with that part. But then funny part comes. From these scenes you can't have combinations where there's rain and dry surface. So you will cross all these combinations. But then what number should you use (in the circle) to multiply these combinations to get the right numbers? To still have only 100 scenes together? I tried to use 18 as that was the n. Of scenes deleted. But it's not giving me the right answer [image]

Comment: You might naturally expect "Dry" to be correlated with "Sunny", though apparently it is possible to have "Rain" and "Sunny" at the same time.  What you cannot do is assume independence and just multiply probabilities when the context makes it implausible

Comment: Can you have rain without clouds? You got 20% cloudy but with 30% it is more often raining.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as a sort of sudoku.

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
a & b & a+b = 0.7 \quad &\text{dry} \\
c & d & c+d =0.3 \quad &\text{rain}\\
\hline 
a+c =0.6 & b+d =0.4 & a+b+c+d 
 \\ \text{dry surf} & \text{wet surf}
\end{array}$$

Add the condition $c=0$ because a dry surface with rain is not possible

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
a & b & a+b = 0.7  \\
0 & d & d = 0.3 \\
\hline 
a = 0.6 & b+d = 0.4 & 1
\end{array}$$

It follows that $a = 0.6$, $d=0.3$, and you can also deduce that $b = 0.1$

Multiply by respectively $0.2$ and $0.8$ to get the cloudy and sunny situations.

---

More generally you can put these systems of equations together

$$\begin{array}{}
 &a&+&b&  &&  & &=& 0.7 \\ 
 &&&&  &c& + &d &=& 0.3 \\ 
 &a&+&&  &c&  & &=& 0.6 \\ 
 &&&b& +  &&  &d &=& 0.4 \\ 
\end{array}$$

and solve it as a matrix equation. (this is useful if you have a larger problem)